# Set query as default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sql query which looks like this:

```
UPDATE TBL_Time
    SET Time = CAST(hours AS VARCHAR(10)) + ':' + CAST(minutes AS VARCHAR(10))
```

I want that query result as the default value for every `Time` column. `hours` and `minutes` are integer type.

Comment: What is the datatype of "Time" field? Is it datetime?

Comment: I hope this is a one-time operation, i.e. you are replacing the hours and minutes columns with a time column instead. (Don't have both hours and minutes columns and a time column...)

Comment: Time is string. I need it that way.

Comment: add WHERE condition like this: WHERE Time is null, so you prevent future re-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `Time` a computed column, and use `CAST(hours AS VARCHAR(10)) + ':' + CAST(minutes AS VARCHAR(10))` as the computation.